# How would I remove a shape from this array using the shape's area?

Tags: java, arrays, object

I have this program that's supposed to add a shape to an array, using its type (rectangle, triangle, circle) and its dimensions (length/width, base/height, radius). It's also supposed to be able to remove a shape from the array. Currently, I can add a shape to the array, but when I try to remove it (which is based on shape type and area, rather than shape type and dimensions), it will print out that it cannot find the shape.

Example: I add a Rectangle with a length of 3 and width of 2. Its area is 6. When I try to remove a Rectangle with an area of 6, it does not remove this rectangle from the array because it supposedly cannot find it.

For clarification, the main issue comes in the removeAShapeDialogue part in the Front-End and the removeShape method in the Collection part of the code.

Notes:

- Shape is an interface
- I cannot create any other classes, methods, or interfaces as per instruction, so there must be a solution using whatever is here.
- I don't think the problem is in the Rectangle, Triangle, or Circle classes
- I'm also having problems with the selection sort in the ShapeCollection class, so any help there would be greatly appreciated.

**Front-End**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ShapeFrontEnd {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Welcome to the Shapes Collection.");
    ShapeCollection shapes = new ShapeCollection();//New instance of ShapeCollection

    boolean quit = false;
    while(!quit)//Runs until quits
    {
        printOptions();
        int pick = keyboard.nextInt();
        keyboard.nextLine();
        switch(pick)
        {
        case 1://Add shape
            shapes.addShape(makeAShapeDialogue());
            break;
        case 2://Remove shape
            shapes.removeShape(removeAShapeDialogue());
            break;
        case 9://Quit
            quit = true;
            System.out.println("Goodbye");
            System.exit(0);
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid input.");
        }
        System.out.println("Current Shapes:");
        shapes.printShapes(shapes);
    }
}
    //Helper Methods
    public static void printOptions()//Prints user's input options
    {
        System.out.println("Enter 1: Add a shape\nEnter 2: Remove a shape\nEnter 9: Quit");
    }
    public static Shape makeAShapeDialogue()//Prints the dialogue after user enters "1"
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        Shape newShape;
        System.out.println("What type of shape? Rectangle, Triangle, or Circle?");
        String shapeType = keyboard.nextLine();

        if(shapeType.equalsIgnoreCase("rectangle"))
        {
            System.out.println("Enter length.");
            double length = keyboard.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Enter height.");
            double height = keyboard.nextDouble();
            keyboard.nextLine();
            newShape = new Rectangle(length, height);
        }
        else if(shapeType.equalsIgnoreCase("triangle"))
        {
            System.out.println("Enter base.");
            double base = keyboard.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Enter height.");
            double height = keyboard.nextDouble();
            keyboard.nextLine();
            newShape = new Triangle(base, height);
        }
        else if(shapeType.equalsIgnoreCase("circle"))
        {
            System.out.println("Enter radius.");
            double radius = keyboard.nextDouble();
            keyboard.nextLine();
            newShape = new Circle(radius);
        }
        else
        {
            newShape = null;
        }
        return newShape;
    }
    public static Shape removeAShapeDialogue()
    {
        ShapeCollection shapes = new ShapeCollection();
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        Shape newShape;

        System.out.println("What type of shape? Rectangle, Triangle, or Circle?");
        String shapeType = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter area.");
        double area = keyboard.nextDouble();
        keyboard.nextLine();

        if(shapeType.equalsIgnoreCase("rectangle"))
        {
            newShape = new Rectangle();
        }
        if(shapeType.equalsIgnoreCase("triangle"))
        {
            newShape = new Triangle();
        }
        if(shapeType.equalsIgnoreCase("circle"))
        {
            newShape = new Circle();
        }
        else
        {
            newShape = null;
        }
        return newShape;
    }
```

}

**Collection/Array Class**

```
public class ShapeCollection {

private Shape[] shapes;
public static final int MAX_SHAPES = 5;

//Constructor
public ShapeCollection()
{
    shapes = new Shape[MAX_SHAPES];
}
//Method to get all the Shapes
public Shape[] getShapes()
{
    return this.shapes;
}

//Add Shape
public void addShape(Shape aShape)
{
    for(int i=0;i<shapes.length;i++)
    {
        if(shapes[i] == null)
        {
            shapes[i] = aShape;
            return;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("You cannot fit any more shapes.");
}
//Remove Shape
public void removeShape(Shape aShape)
//public void removeShape(String aShapeType, double anArea)
{
    for(int i=0;i<shapes.length;i++)
    {
        System.out.println(shapes[i]);
        if(shapes[i] != null && shapes[i].equals(aShape))
        //if(shapes[i] != null && shapes[i].getType().equals(aShapeType) && shapes[i].getArea() == (anArea))
        {
            shapes[i] = null;
            return;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Cannot find that shape.");
}

//Sort Shapes
private void sortShapes()
{
    for(int i=0;i<shapes.length-1;i++)
    {
      int smallestIndex = i;
      for(int j=i+1; j<shapes.length;j++)
      {
        if(shapes[j].getArea() < shapes[smallestIndex].getArea())
        {
          smallestIndex = j;
        }
        /*if(smallestIndex !=i)
        {
          Shape number = shapes[i];
          shapes[i] = shapes[smallestIndex];
          shapes[smallestIndex] = number;
        }*/
      }
      Shape temp = shapes[smallestIndex];
      shapes[smallestIndex] = shapes[i];
      shapes[i] = temp;
    }    
}
//Prints Shapes
public void printShapes(ShapeCollection shapeC)
{
    //sortShapes();
    for(Shape s : shapeC.getShapes())
    {
        if(s == null)
            continue;
                System.out.println(s);
                System.out.println();   
    }
}
```

}

**Shape Interface**

```
public interface Shape {
public double getArea();
public String toString();
public String getType();
}
```

**Rectangle Class**

```
public class Rectangle implements Shape{

//Attributes
private double length;
private double width;

//Constructors
public Rectangle()//Default
{
    this.length = 0.0;
    this.width = 0.0;
}
public Rectangle(double aLength, double aWidth)//Parameterized
{
    this.setLength(aLength);
    this.setWidth(aWidth);
}

//Accessors
public double getLength()
{
    return this.length;
}
public double getWidth()
{
    return this.width;
}

//Mutators
public void setLength(double aLength)
{
    if(aLength>0)
    {
        this.length = aLength;
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Invalid length.");
    }
}
public void setWidth(double aWidth)
{
    if(aWidth>0)
    {
        this.width = aWidth;
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Invalid width.");
    }
}

//Other Methods
public double getArea()
{
    return this.length*this.width;
}
public String getType()
{
    return "RECTANGLE";
}
public String toString()
{
    return getType() + " | Length: " + this.length + " | Width: " + this.width + " | Area: " + getArea();
}
}
```

**Triangle Class**

```
public class Triangle implements Shape{

//Attributes
private double base;
private double height;

//Constructors
public Triangle()
{
    this.base = 0.0;
    this.height = 0.0;
}
public Triangle(double aBase, double aHeight)
{
    this.setBase(aBase);
    this.setHeight(aHeight);
}

//Accessors
public double getBase()
{
    return this.base;
}
public double getHeight()
{
    return this.height;
}

//Mutators
public void setBase(double aBase)
{
    if(aBase>0)
    {
        this.base = aBase;
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Invalid base.");
    }
}
public void setHeight(double aHeight)
{
    if(aHeight>0)
    {
        this.height = aHeight;
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Invalid height.");
    }
}

//Other Methods
public double getArea()
{
    return (this.base*this.height)/2;
}
public String getType()
{
    return "TRIANGLE";
}
public String toString()
{
    return getType() + " | Base: " + this.base + " | Height: " + this.height + " | Area: " + getArea();
}
}
```

**Circle Class**

```
public class Circle implements Shape{

//Attributes
private double radius;

//Constructors
public Circle()
{
    this.radius = 0.0;
}
public Circle(double aRadius)
{
    this.setRadius(aRadius);
}

//Accessors
public double getRadius()
{
    return this.radius;
}

//Mutators
public void setRadius(double aRadius)
{
    if(aRadius>0)
    {
        this.radius = aRadius;
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Invalid radius.");
    }
}

//Other Methods
public double getArea()
{
    return Math.PI*(radius*radius);
}
public String getType()
{
    return "CIRCLE";
}
public String toString()
{
    return getType() + " | Radius: " + this.radius + " | Area: " + getArea();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're comparing shapes using their `equals` method: `shapes[i].equals(aShape)` but you haven't implemented it, so you're really comparing using the default `Object.equals()` method, which doesn't know what `Shape` is, and instead compares the Object's references.

Comment: So I would just create an `equals` method in the Rectangle, Triangle, and Circle classes, correct?

Comment: Create it and implement it according to the logic you want for comparing these shapes.

Comment: @DanielZippel As a side note, your question is clear and understandable, but it would help posting less (irrelevant) code. No one wants to read all of that. Just post the relevant bits and pieces: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Okay thanks. Usually I post not enough code and have been stuck on this for days so I just decided to post it all. Not really sure what's needed to help people understand the problem.

Comment: That's understandable. Take a look at that link though (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it's a 30 second read, and it will help you both with your debugging and with asking questions.